# Max/Min modulus principle.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be analytic function  inside and on a bounded domain $D$.

If $\Re(f)$ is constant on the boundary, then $f$ is constant in $D$.

I realized that maximum value of $\Re(f)$ must occur on the boundary, but I am not sure why minimum value of $\Re(F)$ also occurs on the boundary of $D$.

Can anyone explicitly state what Max/Min modules principle is ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumModulusPrinciple.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumModulusPrinciple.html

Comment: minimum modulus require f non-zero on $D$. Proof is using max modulus on $1/f$.

Comment: How can I show that it has a min on the boundary?

Comment: I know that Re(f) is max on the boundary, then 1/Re(f) is min on the boundary. Is that it?

Comment: $|f|$ not $Re(f)$ and yes if $f$ nonzero max of $|f|$ is min of $|1/f|$

Comment: So, if f is analytic on a bounded domain and never vanishes, then f attains max and min on the boundary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39260/discussion-between-frank000-and-jessie).

Answer (score 1):

Any harmonic function must attain both its maximum and minimum on the boundary of any compact set $D$.  The real part of any holomorphic function is harmonic.

If $\Re(f)$ is constant on the boundary of $D$, then $\Re(f)$ is constant on $D$ by the above.  By the Cauchy-Riemann equations, $\Im(f)$ is also constant, so $f$ is constant.

---

Further explanation:

$\Re(f)$ is harmonic; this follows from Cauchy-Riemann.

A basic property of harmonic functions is that, if $g$ is harmonic, and $g$ is defined in an $\epsilon$-ball around $x$, then $g(x)$ equals the average value of $g$ on $B(x,\epsilon)$ (also, the average value of $g$ on the surface of $B(x,\epsilon)$).  It follows that if $g$ attains a maximum (or minimum) at a point $x$ in the interior of $D$, then $g$ is constant in any ball around $x$.

Comment: I am confused why harmonic has to reach min and max on its boundary, and from that How can I conclude that Re(f) is constant on D

Comment: @jessie See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the analytic function $\exp(f)$. By the min/max modulus principle, $|\exp(f)| = \exp(\Re(f))$ must be min/max on the boundary of $D$. Since the real exponential is an increasing function, you get the conclusion.

Comment: Can we show something similar about the imaginary part of $f$?